# How to remove unwanted numbers from the list?

Tags: python, list

I have this below code written to remove numbers greater than 5 from the list.
But it does not work though the code looks fine to me. I'm new to python and trying to get my basics right. I decided to use remove since i'm checking based on the value

```
a = [1,5,4,6,3,8,9,5,9] 
for i in a:
    print (i)
    if i<=5:
        continue
    a.remove(i)
print (a)
```

Result - `[1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 9]`

Comment: Interesting.  What happens if you use `for i in reversed(a):` instead of `for i in a:`?

Comment: You can use array for making your life simpler. `a = np.array([1,5,4,6,3,8,9,5,9])` and then `a = a[a<5]` will give you what you want

Comment: Or with a list comprehension: `a = [c for c in a if c <= 5 ]`

Comment: @wim works perfectly fine when i use reversed(a)

Comment: Or with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter): `filter(lambda x: x<=5, a)`

Answer (score 0):

it will not work because you are removing item from list while iterating the same one....so when you remove an element, next iteration you will jump one one them.

Solution:
1) use 2 array;
2) use a while loop and when you remove an element you decrease the len of the array and you don't increment the iteration

```
a = [1,5,4,6,3,8,9,5,9]
i=0
l=len(a)
while i<l:
    if a[i]>5:
        a.pop(i)
        l-=1
    else:
        i+=1
print (a)
```

Result:

```
[1, 5, 4, 3, 5]
```

Comment: how does it work when i use reversed(a) in my code. I thought it would skip based on the above explanation

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/reversed